# Why do I keep getting this error: SQL command not properly ended for insert into values?

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

```
INSERT into L5_DIRECTORS (director_id, first_name, last_name)
 Values
            (1010, 'Rob', 'Minkoff'),
            (1020, 'Bill', 'Condon'),
            (1050, 'Josh', 'Cooley'),
            (2010, 'brad', 'bird'),
            (3020, 'lake', 'bell');
```

EDIT: I figured it out, I had to write each row individually and run it, I do not why it would not work all together but thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Have you tried to run it without semicolon in the end of the statement?

Comment: @GSazheniuk yes I just tried it and still same error

Comment: Unfortunately, Oracle is still lacking the standard SQL `VALUES` clause (except for one row only in the insert statement). You can vote for this feature here: https://community.oracle.com/tech/apps-infra/discussion/4391390/add-support-for-the-values-constructor

Answer (score 1):

Oracle does not allow you to insert multiple rows using the `VALUES` syntax.  I recommend just using `insert . . select`:

```
INSERT into L5_DIRECTORS (director_id, first_name, last_name)
    SELECT 1010, 'Rob', 'Minkoff' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 1020, 'Bill', 'Condon' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 1050, 'Josh', 'Cooley' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 2010, 'brad', 'bird' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 3020, 'lake', 'bell' FROM DUAL;
```